# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Exposing multiple ports not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to expose two ports from my app. My `Dockerrun.aws.json` is:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "node:12",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "4444"
    },
    {
      "ContainerPort": "4445",
      "HostPort": "81"
    }
  ]
}
```

But port port `80` is working fine on `www.fakeexample.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` but second port is not working `www.fakeexample.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:81`.

I don`t know why, do I need any changes in Beanstalk dashboard?

Comment: Did you check the Security Group and Network ACL rules? Maybe there’s something blocking the traffic on port 81.

Comment: @DennisTraub This option is not in `Elastic Beanstalk - Configuration overview`

Comment: Or where can I find this settings?

Comment: any resolution on this?